# Simple algebra open parenthesis question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a stupid question, but I can't remember how to open parenthesis on $(32-x)^2$?

My full exercise is :

$$x^2 = 24^2 + (32-x)^2$$

But I can solve it if I'd remember how to open the parenthesis

Thanks

Comment: sorry guy's I edited the question, it was 24 not 12, this is why the answer is x = 25 @GitGud

Comment: @GitGud Oh my...sorry.

Comment: @julien Don't apologize to me, I'll feel obligated to thank you for  every time I learned something from you, but life is finite and I can't afford to do that.

Comment: @GitGud You really are too kind, but thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** $(32-x)^2=(32-x)(32-x)$.

Comment: @user804968 That's correct (after the edit).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$

Comment: I find the word *hint* not quite right here.